# How to properly display coordinates on MapKit Map in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm working on a map that displays the location of a vineyard that makes a particular wine and am unable to display negative coordinates.

The coordinates for a winery in northern California I got from Google maps are: (38.65680447392557, -122.84383931534359) but when I display them like so:

```
struct VineyardMapView: View {
    @State var vineyard: Vineyard
    @State var mapCamera: MapCameraPosition = MapCameraPosition.automatic
    
    var body: some View {
        //How to zoom map out??
        Map(position: $mapCamera) {
            Marker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: vineyard.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: vineyard.location.coordinate.latitude), label: {Image(systemName: "mappin")})
        }
        .mapStyle(.imagery)
        .frame(width: 350, height: 400)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
        .onAppear {
            //load Map Camera position at runtime
            mapCamera = MapCameraPosition.region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: vineyard.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: vineyard.location.coordinate.latitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VineyardMapView(vineyard: Vineyard("Jordan",
                                       CLLocation(latitude: 38.6562, longitude: -122.8438),
                                       "https://www.jordanwinery.com/"))
}
```

It places me somewhere in the middle east:
**Ex:**

[image: map example]

Can someone explain how to properly display coordinates both positive and negative on a mapkit map in swiftUI?

Comment: What's wrong with what your code currently produces? What did you want it to display instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the vineyard's latitude for both the latitude and longitude when initializing the `Marker` and the `MapCameraPosition`.

i.e. `longitude: vineyard.location.coordinate.latitude` should be `.longitude`.

Resulting coordinate, `(38.65680447392557, 38.65680447392557)` is in Turkey, as shown.

Comment: Good spot. One could reduce the chances of errors like this by directly passing in the coordinate struct, e.g. `Marker(coordinate: vineyard.location.coordinate, label: {Image(systemName: "mappin")})`